# how to reset alarm() in c linux

Tags: c

Once the `alarm(5)` or what ever seconds is started and running, after some time in the program if some actions happens I need to reset the alarm again to `alarm(5)`. How can I achieve this?

Any alarm `reset()` available?

```
int flag=0;
void alarmhand(int signal)
{ 
  flag=1;
  // printf("\n time out");
}

void main()
{
  signal(SIGALRM,alarmhand);
  alarm (5);
  while(1)
  {
   event_status();
   if(flag==1)
       break;
  } 
}

void event_status()
{
  int reset;
  printf("reset 1=y/2=n :");
  scanf("%d",&reset);
  if(reset==1)
  {
   // alarm.reset(5);
  // HOW DO I RESET THE ALARM AGAIN TO 5 HERE ??
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just set the new alarm and the old one will be cancelled:

```
alarm (5);
```

From the [Linux `alarm` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/alarm), slightly paraphrased):

> `alarm()` arranges for a `SIGALRM` signal to be delivered to the calling process in a specified number of seconds.
>
> If the specified number of seconds is zero, no new alarm is scheduled.
>
> In any event any previously set alarm is canceled.

As noted, any *current* alarm is cancelled by a call to `alarm()` before anything else. A new one won't be created if the argument to `alarm()` is zero.

So `alarm(0)` will cancel any currently active alarm, while `alarm(5)` will either create a new alarm of, or reset a currently active alarm to, 5 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

To cancel an outstanding `alarm()`, use `alarm(0)`.  Its return value tells you how much time was unused from the last call to `alarm()`.  You can then freely set a new alarm, of course.

Answer (score -1):

Use `sigaction()` system call and handle alarm signal in starting only. 
Use ISR function to reset the alarm for every action when you want.